# Checkstyle installed, but not displaying in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have installed the CheckStyle plugin for Eclipse.

[image]

The CheckStyle guide says to right click on your project, click properties and click CheckStyle.  Except that it's not there:

[image]

I tried reinstalling it, but it just says that checkstyle is already installed.  I restarted Eclipse and restarted my computer.  Eclipse says it's installed, but I have yet to see any evidence of that.  Can anybody help me get checkstyle working properly?

Answer (score 0):

Try starting eclipse with the -clean -refresh parameters.